# Bing Map Route API : Route point showing lat, long not address

Tags: bing-maps

When click on grid item, I pass lat and long for source and destination and route display on the map.

But everytime I see latitude and longitude on [A] and [B] route point instead of address.

So how to display address on [A] and [B] point instead of lat, long ?

[image]

Following is my code.

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', () => {

      that.directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(that.map);
      that.directionsManager.clearAll();
      // Set Route Mode to driving
      that.directionsManager.setRequestOptions({
        routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving
      });

      that.directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
        drivingPolylineOptions: {
          strokeThickness: 3
        }
      });

      const waypoint1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
        location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(that.truckData.currentLat, that.truckData.currentLong)
      });

      const waypoint2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
        location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(that.truckData.workLat, that.truckData.workLong)
      });

      that.directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint1);
      that.directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint2);

that.directionsManager.calculateDirections();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something else to display instead of the coordinates, pass it into the address property of the waypoints as shown in this code sample: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/directionscreatedrivingroute

Comment: Thank Ricky for reply. I already saw this link. My concern is I have only latitude and longitude  for source and destination available to get route on the map. And that's why [A] and [B] is showing that only. I don't have direct address for source and destination.

Comment: In that case you have two options; one is to reverse geocode the coordinates before calculating the route. The other is to hide the waypoints, add a directions update event to the directions manager, then create pushpins for the waypoints based on the returned route information.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I already tried reverse geocode approach but I am getting too much delay and due to that route is getting displayed with lat long only. I thought there might be a way to get address from route api.